# Proving that for any 3 infinite sequences $\{a_n\},\{b_n\},\{c_n\}$ in $\Bbb N,\exists p,q\in\Bbb N$ s. t. $a_p\ge a_q,b_p\ge b_q,c_p\ge c_q.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, contest-math

> Prove that for any three infinite sequences $\{a_n\},\{b_n\},\{c_n\}$ in $\Bbb N$, there are distinct $p,q\in\Bbb N$ s. t. $$a_p\ge a_q\space\land\space b_p\ge b_q\space\land\space c_p\ge c_q.$$

The task appeared on the [$1961$ All Soviet Union Olympiad](https://artofproblemsolving.com/downloads/printable_post_collections/114577).

---

My attempt:

I tried to use the following lemma:

> Every sequence in $\{x_n\}$ in $\Bbb R$ has a monotonic subsequence.

and its corollary:

> For finitely many sequences $a^{(1)},a^{(2)},\ldots,a^{(k)}$ there is a strictly increasing subsequence $p:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ s. t. all of the subsequences $a^{(1)}\circ p,a^{(2)}\circ p,\ldots,a^{(k)}\circ p$ are monotonic.

and the proof of the corollary is:

> From the lemma, we know there a strictly increasing sequence $q^{(1)}:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ s. t. $a^{(1)}\circ q^{(1)}$ is a monotonic subsequence of $a^{(1)}$. We now look at the subsequences $a^{(1)}\circ q^{(1)},a^{(2)}\circ q^{(1)},\ldots,a^{(k)}\circ q^{(1)}$ where the first one is monotonic, while others don't have to be. Again, from the lemma, there is a strictly increasing sequence $q^{(2)}:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ s. t. $a^{(2)}\circ q^{(1)}\circ q^{(2)}$ is a monotonic subsequence of $a^{(2)}\circ q^{(1)}$. Since a subsequence of a monotonic sequence is also monotonic, among the subsequences $a^{(1)}\circ q^{(1)}\circ q^{(2)},a^{(2)}\circ q^{(1)}\circ q^{(2)},\ldots,a^{(k)}\circ q^{(1)}\circ q^{(2)}$, the first two are monotonic, while others don't have to be. We repeat the process $(k-2)$ more times and obtain the subsequences $a^{(1)}\circ p,a^{(2)}\circ p,\ldots,a^{(k)}\circ p$, where $p=q^{(1)}\circ q^{(2)}\circ\cdots\circ q^{(k)}$.

To avoid confusion, let $d:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ take the role of the strictly increasing sequence $p:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ from the corollary of the lemma.

Now, every sequence in $\Bbb N$ has a minimum element, so, if some of the sequences $a\circ d,b\circ d,c\circ d$ happen to be *decreasing*, at some point they should become constant and hence monotonically *increasing* so, e.g., if $a'=a\circ d$ is decreasing $$\space m_a=\min\{m\in\Bbb N\mid\space a'_l\ge a'_m,l> m\},$$ and if we similarly define $m_b,m_c$ (if necessary), $p=\max\{m_a,m_b,m_c\}$, and any $q\ge p$ should work as we end up with three monotonically increasing sequences $a\circ d,b\circ d,c\circ d$ starting from the index $p$.

---

May I ask if this argument is valid and if there is anything wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems to me that everything you say is OK but your proof is yet incomplete. You say : "if some of the sequences $a\circ p,b\circ p,c\circ p$ happen to be decreasing", but what if some are increasing and others are decreasing ? It's not difficult but you don't say how it's done. Also, when you say "the proof is", you might say "the proof (of the corollary from the lemma) is" for greater clarity.

Comment: Thank you @EwanDelanoy, if some sequence is decreasing and becomes constant, it also becomes monotonically increasing. To avoid confusion, I changed the name of the sequence $p$ to $d$ as $p\in\Bbb N$ is the index I'm looking for. I've also corrected $p=\color{red}{\max}\{\ldots\}$

Comment: It looks like this is the right approach.  You can shorten and clarify the last part "Now, every sequence..." by noting that all monotonic sequences in $\mathbb{N}$ are either non-decreasing and unbounded or eventually constant.

Comment: @HansEngler, thank you very much for the verification & feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this as a community wiki so that this question doesn't appear in the unanswered queue.

---

As verified by @HansEngler in the comments, the last paragraph of my proof can be summarized by noting that:

> All monotonic sequences in $\Bbb N$ are either non-decreasing and unbounded or eventually constant.